# Rollback is not working if the storedproce call another storedproc

Tags: mysql, mariadb, stored-procedures, transaction, rollback

Is it intended behavior that if I call a `stored procedure` inside a `stored procedure` will automatically commit?

example:

pseudo procedure proc1

```
create procedure proc1(in var1 int, out var2 int)
begin
  start transaction;
  -- some code here
  commit;
end
```

pseudo procedure proc2, the one will call the proc1

```
create procedure proc2()
lbl_begin:
begin
  start transaction;
    -- modify some data here
    call proc1(0, var2);

    if var != 0 then
      rollback;
      leave lbl_begin;
    end;
  commit;
end;
```

Even the rollback on proc2 is executed, the data modified before the call of the proc1 is still committed.

Is it a bug or its an intended behavior?

Comment: Normal behavior.  You need to learn to commit ALL your work...or none of it.  See ACID Compliant for more info.

Comment: @MichaelKutz no my concern is when I tried to rollback the data is still committed.

Comment: Thsts because you called `commit`

Comment: I edited the question few hours ago, and set ```if var != 0 then```  rollback and exit the stored procedure that wont execute the ```commit```.

Comment: Do you get the same thing if you avoid using stored procs?

Comment: @RickJames yes, here what I did https://pastebin.com/GbmDbvNK I purposefully omit the commit and just do a  rollback, but the first insert stills was able to go through.

Comment: @RickJames sorry I think I misunderstand your question. here is the output I copied from the terminal. https://pastebin.com/51bNKPS8 I manual execute the command instead putting it inside the stored procedure.

Comment: `BEGIN` _outside_ a SP is synonymous with `START TRANSACTION`.  Your 2nd example starts _4_ transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Beginning a transaction causes any pending transaction to be committed. See Section 13.3.3, “Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit”, for more information.

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

and

> Transactions cannot be nested. This is a consequence of the implicit commit performed for any current transaction when you issue a START TRANSACTION statement or one of its synonyms.

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

That is, proc1's `START` closed proc2's `START`.

The first `ROLLBACK` closes the only open transaction, hence the second `ROLLBACK` has nothing to "roll back".

Comment: I started over and found documentation.